# How to Add (+) up integers in a field and print a total count in Python 2.7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-2.7

I'm a complete beginner to python. I have what I hope to be a simple question. I want to run a bit of script in IDLE so that it adds up all figures in a table under attribute name "Tot_Aff". When I run the below it just gives me each Value. Any help would be great

```
fc = final_SOA
field = "Tot_Aff"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    print row.getValue(field)
```

I want to add up all the integers

Answer (score 4):

You're nearly there, you just need to accumulate. Start by initializing a variable (total) to 0 and then for each row add the value to the total like this:

```
Total = 0
field = "Tot_Aff"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

for row in cursor:
    Total += row.getValue(field)

print("Total is : %d" % Total)
```

Null values will mess with this, to keep it simple I haven't included a test for them.

Comment: Hi there Michael, that worked thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: To account for None (Null) values, simply change the 5th line of code to this:  `Total += row.getValue(field) or 0`

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to just add up the values on the fly, using a cursor may be a good option.  If you're going to need more statistics than just a sum or if you're going to want to save or re-use the value, you may want to look at using the Summary Statistics Tool: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000

There should be python code samples for it on the tool help page.  Like I said, you could easily also use a cursor for this as you are suggesting and there appears to be another answer that covers the cursor method, but, I figured I'd throw this out there as another option to go about it a different way.

Comment: That's a great way of doing it, faster and in a single line, you can get the sum (what you're after), min, max, median.... it needs an Advanced (INFO) license but there's no such thing as a free lunch! Using the cursor method to sum can be done in Basic (View) and as a bonus gives an insight into how cursors work.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Only Basic level license is needed for Summary Statistics

Comment: @PolyGeo Sorry, I must have got confused with 'Frequency' which does similar things but does require an Advanced license.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Michael Miles-Stimsons answer, which works but is kinda un-pythonic I would suggest this:

```
field = "Tot_Aff"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
total = sum([row.getValue(field) for row in cursor])    
print("Total is : %d" % total)
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of a generator.  You will likely get even more performance improvements by using the `da` module with the Search Cursor.

Comment: I don't know anything about the arcpy-library, so there might be better ways to do this ;)

Answer (score 0):

if a single line of code is what you are looking for then maybe this will be helpful
`total = sum([x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('FeaturClass',("FieldName"))])`